# Best cross platform practices for dealing with a fatal error in C?

Tags: c, vulkan

Outside of logging the failure to stderr and a log file, how should I deal with a fatal error?

example:

```
VkResult result = vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, NULL, &vulkanInfo->instance);
if (result != VK_SUCCESS) {
    // ???
}
```

If vkCreateInstance fails, it's all over. The app cannot continue. What should I do?

Targets are Windows, Mac, Linux, Switch, and more.

I realize this is a very open ended question. I’m just curious how the great minds here deal with it.

Comment: What OS? Is an error dialog as part of a graceful exit out of the question? It is hard to say given the limited information in your question.

Comment: `exit(ERROR); `

Comment: Updated to say cross platform. Windows, Linux, Mac, Switch, etc.

Comment: `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`. `What should I do?` You should do _app specific logic_ to handle to error. There is no general answer. For one application this may be a fatal error, for an application that tests if `vkCreateInstance` works this is just a return value. The operating system is not relevant. What do you _want_ your application to do in this case?

Comment: Just looking for general opinions. I realize it's a very open ended question.

Comment: also, you can use `errx(1, "Critical error, exiting...");` from `<err.h>`

Comment: @vlad that wouldn't be portable :p - `err.h` is a nonstandad header from BSD systems ported to glibc.

Comment: @jestro Also not really that much of a Vulkan specific question.

Answer (score 3):

> how should I deal with a fatal error?
>
> The app cannot continue

Because `The app cannot continue` you should stop your application. A properly written application would:

- print an error message to `stderr`
- stop and join and synchronize all threads
- free all dynamically allocated memory
- close all open files
- generally clean up all shared resources if needed (I think of shared memory)
- exit the application with an error

To be (almost extremely unnecessarily) portable, you can use `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` to notify the system that your application exited with an error (but better use `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` for readability). For the platforms you target, use `exit()` with any other value than 0 - `exit(0)` means application succeeded. For many applications, some specific exit values are also used to notify the upper application of what specific error happened, [like `grep`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1p.html#EXIT_STATUS) exits 0 if it filtered some lines, 1 if no lines were filtered, and other exit codes if an error occurred (like for example the file does not exist).

Answer (score 2):

> Best cross platform practices for dealing with a fatal error in C?

Your code is dealing with Vulkan, so it's reasonable to assume that almost everyone using your software will be using a GUI and will not look at (and never see) anything sent to `stdout` or `stderr`. Instead; they will expect a "GUI specific notification" (a dialog box).

There's multiple different "cross platform GUI toolkit" libraries online to choose from (if you don't feel like writing a minimal wrapper for a dialog box and nothing else).

Comment: Great point! This is what I will do on Desktop.